# Is it possible to see if a comment has been "posted to facebook"?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments

I am using the [facebook comments plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) to allow users to post comments on my page. This plugin provides the commenters with a checkbox: "Post to Facebook". Is there any way for me to see if a comment posted on my page via the plugin had this checkbox checked or not?
It doesn't seem possible according to the [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/).

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to tell if the button is checked or not. Why would you want to tell anyway? The only difference between 'Post to Facebook' and not is the comment will be displayed on their timeline if checked. i.e. nothing to do with your side

Comment: Ok, I assumed having 'Post to Facebook' meant that the commenters friends would see that he posted on my page and could therefore reply to his comment. And not having 'Post to Facebook' meant that only other people reading the same page on my site would see the comment and be able to reply. Is that incorrect?

Comment: No. That is correct. The link and his comment will go up on his timeline. Therefore his friends should also be able to comment and like it. These comments will then appear across your site as well

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. The reason this is interesting to me is that I have hundreds of pages on my site and many users, most of their comments are questions and it's impossible for me to answer all of them. If I could see whether the question is also seen by friends it could help me prioritise which questions to answer. That is if friends also see the question then maybe they can answer the questions being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FQL to access the comments.

fb:comments has a field which also contains replys to the comment.

If the user posts to Facebook and gets replies from his friends you can track the replies and the number of replies using the above query language.

That's the best you can do. You can't check if he has reposted to Facebook but this will allow you to see how many people commented on his post and how many likes he has and hopefully decide priority from it

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/

Comment: Since it's not possible to check if the user checked the 'Post to Facebook' checkbox, I guess this is the closest I can get to what I want